# Play Framework Specs2 Test - FakeApplication in multi-project

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, automated-tests, specs2

I've read https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/SBTSubProjects to create a project composed of multiple Play applications.
There are three Play sub-projects in *modules* directory.
I need to write some automatic test with Play Specs2.

Is there a way to run different Play sub-projects in different FakeApplication instances in the same test file?
For instance, I have a Specs2 file in *modules/serviceA/test* directory and I need to run both serviceA and serviceB.
I have tried to change the *path* of FakeApplication in the following way:

```
val applicationA = new FakeApplication(new File("../modules/serviceA/."))
val applicationB = new FakeApplication(new File("../modules/serviceB/."))
```

but it didn't work. Same issues if I use absolute path of sub-projects.
Thanks in advance.